# SQL stored procedure that enters a new person, using default value for state

Tags: sql

Learning, be kind.

I need to do a stored procedure that enters a new author, but also sets state to a default value.  Also, check if authorid already exists and if not, give an error.  How do I go about this, I am rather lost.

This is what I have so far...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE NEW_AUTHOR_DEFAULT_STATE
AS
SELECT a.au_id, a.state
FROM authors a JOIN titleauthors ta
ON a.au_id = ta.au_id
WHERE a.state = 'WA'
```

Comment: A stored procedure would start with `create procedure`.

Comment: I suggest doing things one thing at a time.  Get the queries to work on their own, then put them into a stored procedure.

Comment: Does “enters a new author” mean to create a new record in the `authors` table? The code you posted tries to retrieve an existing author, it doesn't create anything.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? It often does make a difference whether you're using MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server or IBM DB2 - or something else even. Please add a relevant tag to your question!

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE NEW_AUTHOR_DEFAULT_STATE
(
   @State VARCHAR(100)
)
AS
SELECT @State = (CASE WHEN (LEN(@State) < 1) OR @State IS NULL THEN 'WA' ELSE @State END)

INSERT INTO NEWTABLE (au_id, State)
SELECT  a.au_id ,
        a.state
FROM    authors a
        JOIN titleauthors ta ON a.au_id = ta.au_id
WHERE   a.state = @State
```